# Tile map isn’t loaded with some images

Tags: tile, cocos2d-js

I made a tilemap. and used it on cocos2d-js.

Just added

```
this._map = new cc.TMXTiledMap(res.tilemap);
this.addChild(this._map, 0, 1);
```

in Layer.

But When I use this image,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUbhu.png,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1gHS.png

this error occured.

```
[.WebGLRenderingContext]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture
unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible
texture filtering or is not 'texture complete'
```

But When I used other image, it works. 
like

https://i.stack.imgur.com/efT6q.png,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5qhT.png,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZVpf.png

I changed tilemap many times with that images, but same result.
I don't know what is diffrent that images.
Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried I believe I encountered this error once:

Have you tried adding all the image files in your `resources.js` file?